# Snowflake qualify query error 'Invalid data type [NUMBER(18,0)] for predicate [RANK()'

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to run a query in Snowflake that uses the rank() function along with qualify to try and take the best match between two columns (using editdistance) and I'm getting the following error:

Invalid data type [NUMBER(18,0)] for predicate [RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY key1 ORDER BY  editdistance(name1, name2) ASC NULLS LAST)]

Query looks like this:

```
select
  key1,
  key2
from
  table
qualify
  rank() over ( 
    partition by key1 order by editdistance(name1, name2) asc
  )
```

I'm really not clear on what number the error is referring to. name1/name2 are both varchar, key1 is a varchar. Hoping someone might have a pointer for me.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: You need to provide a value for the QUALIFY function so it should be something like: qualify
  rank() over ( 
    partition by key1 order by editdistance(name1, name2) asc
  ) = 1

Comment: This was it, dumb mistake on my part, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The QUALIFY works similar to WHERE,but it is evaluated at different point during query execution. QUALIFY requires a predicate, which should evaluate to boolean.

[QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html):

> ```
> QUALIFY <predicate>
> ```

---

The expression:

```
rank() over (partition by key1 order by editdistance(name1, name2))
```

returns NUMBER.

Comparing the result to integer fixes the error:

```
rank() over (partition by key1 order by editdistance(name1, name2)) = 1
```

It is worth noting that there may be tie in the data, i.e, same distance per key for more than one row, for that situation it is safer to use [DENSE_RANK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dense_rank.html):

```
dense_rank() over (partition by key1 order by editdistance(name1, name2)) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Dean identified the problem in his comment above so just moving it to an answer to close the loop on this:

> You need to provide a value for the QUALIFY function so it should be something like: qualify rank() over ( partition by key1 order by editdistance(name1, name2) asc ) = 1